# Ngxs store is loosing state after pressing F5 to refresh the browser

Tags: angular, ngxs

I am trying to preserve state between page refresh but it seems to loose the state information. I am trying to save two boolean values and retrieve it. I have installed NGXS Dev tool for chrome to inspect the state. I can see the action is correctly dispatching the state information but looses that information when i press F5. What am i missing ?

Action

```
import { AgreementsStateModel } from '../models/agreements-state.model';

export class SetAgreementStatus {
    static readonly type = '[AGREEMENT] SetAgreementStatus';
    constructor(public payload: AgreementsStateModel) {}
}
```

State

```
 import { Action, Selector, State, StateContext } from '@ngxs/store';
    import { AgreementsStateModel } from '../models/agreements-state.model';
    import { SetAgreementStatus } from './agreement.actions';



@State<AgreementsStateModel>({
  name: 'agreementModalState',
  defaults: {
       isDeferred: false,
       isInteracted: false
  }
})
export class AgreementState {

  constructor() { }

  @Selector()
  static agreement(state: AgreementsStateModel) {
    return state;
  }

  @Action(SetAgreementStatus)
  setAgreementStatus({ patchState }: StateContext<AgreementsStateModel>, { payload }: SetAgreementStatus) {
    patchState(payload);
  }
}
```

AppModule imports

```
NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot()
```

Dispatching the state

```
  this.store.dispatch(new SetAgreementStatus({isInteracted: true, isDeferred: true}));
```

Reading state information

```
     @Select(AgreementState.agreement) agreementModalState$: Observable<AgreementsStateModel>;

  this.agreementModalState$.subscribe(agreementModalStatus => {
      this.agreementModalStatus = agreementModalStatus;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

So the NGRX Store, wont preserve information during a refresh. You will have to use the users `localStorage` or other local storage to store this information.

One way you can do this is in your reducer you could also store the same information you are setting in your store in the users `localStorage` then when you refresh, you can grab any info you have stored, and populate your store.

There are many libraries that try and simplify this like [ngrx-store-localstorage](https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage) that sync the store and the users `localStorage` so you dont lose state between refreshes

but by default the ngrx store **will not** save information between page refreshes

Comment: Smokey Dawson is definitely correct in most of everything said, however I will point out Tom is leveraging NGXS which is not the same as NGRX.  Please take a look at this page on NGXS docs for the correct plugin. https://www.ngxs.io/plugins/storage

Comment: Actually now that I have read your post I see you are leveraging the correct plugin.  I do not see anything glaringly wrong here.  Perhaps post a stackblitz reproduction, we can look at?

Comment: Also, please confirm you have your state class in the NgxsModule.forRoot() method....

Answer (score 0):

When the page is refreshed, the state managed by NGXS is reset to its initial values. If you need to keep the data after the refreshes you can store that data on local storage or session storage.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).